# Outlook new email is not being populated

Tags: opentext, guptateamdeveloper

In Opentext team developer 7.0 when I try to use QuickMail it does not populate Outlook new email msg.

```
If tblQuickMail.ExecNew( )
    Set tblQuickMail.Recipients = 'testemail@yahoo.com'
    Set tblQuickMail.Subject = 'test'
    Set tblQuickMail.Text = 'testing'
    Call tblQuickMail.ExecSend( )
```

It just opens a blank email. Why?

Answer (score 1):

i had copied and pasted tblQuickMail from another app.
I had to remove that and add the class in.
and change its tblQuickMail settings (like not populate on create) and run from the .exe, not the .app  to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Pasting class based objects is always dubious, and usually you end up recreating manually.

Also,  suggest you try the native Gupta SalMail instead of QuickMail.  I swapped to SalMail and it works great without all the drama of QuickObjects.